# How to pass variables to custom ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, action-filter

What are my options for passing variables into my `MyCustomAttribute` class?

Currently the class is defined as:

```
public class MyCustomAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string MyIDParam { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var myID = filterContext.ActionParameters[MyIDParam] as Int32?;

        // logic
    }
}
```

Now in my controller I have this:

```
[MyCustomAttribute(MyIDParam = "id")]
public ActionResult Report(int id)
{
    Guid userId = GetUserInfo();

    // logic
}
```

In this case I would like to be able to pass `id` and `userId` to `MyCustomAttribute` class.

Is this possible? Doesn't the `MyCustomAttribute` get executed before the contents of the `Report` method?

Comment: Yeah, you can't do that. Like you say, the action filter code is executed before the action.

Comment: You can get it indirectly using the request context : `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Params["id"]`

Comment: @PaulDS And how about passing `userId`? Like I said, this isn't possible.

Comment: Indeed, I missed this information in the question. You cannot get directly this information.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation.  I'm still learning MVC and I wanted to be sure that this wasn't possible.  I'll have to try a different approach.

Comment: Wow some of these comments are incorrect.  Just because the action hasn't executed doesn't mean values don't exist.  The user is available *long* before the controller is even constructed.  Route values (controller method parameters) have to be created before the controller is constructed as well because they are used to identify the controller/action from the MapRoutes.

Comment: This includes parameters as it's possible to create Route Constraint which interrogates the parameters to validate a MapRoute can handle the request.

Answer (score 0):

> What are my options for passing variables into my MyCustomAttribute class?

Well you're writing a custom `ActionFilter` which MVC passes the `ActionExecutingContext`.  That variable contains a ton of information at your disposal.

```
public class MyCustomAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
    var myID = filterContext
      .RouteData["id"] as int?

    var user = filterContext.Controller.User;
  }
}
```

> In this case I would like to be able to pass "id" and "userId" to MyCustomAttribute class.

No you can't pass them in, you have to retreive them from the [ActionExecutingContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionexecutingcontext(v=vs.118).aspx).

> Doesn't the MyCustomAttribute get executed before the contents of the Report method?

Maybe? Depends on which method your override.

The [ActionFilterAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) has a few different points at which it executes.  Here is a break down:

```
ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecuting()  // Action Filter

public ActionResult Report(int id) // MVC Action is Called

ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecuted()  // Action Filter

ActionFiltrAttribute.OnResultExecuting()  // Action Filter

ActionResult.Execute() // MVC ActionResult Execute is Called

ActionFilterAttribute.OnResultExecuted()  // Action Filter
```

You can see that [these methods have been available to access to all this data](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) all the way back since [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) version 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can gain that ability by adding support for referencing action parameters within your custom attribute.

```
[MyCustomAttribute("The parameter for id is {id}")]
public ActionResult Report(int id)
{
    Guid userId = GetUserInfo();

    ... logic ...
}
```

At runtime, your custom attribute can substitute the value of the referenced parameter for the placeholder.
So for doing this ability, you need only to hook into the ActionExecuting method to grab those actions parameters:

```
    private IDictionary<string, object> _parameters;
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        _parameters = filterContext.ActionParameters;
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```

Then inside your `OnActionExecuted` method, you can create a variable to processed field. Then you can go through each parameter in the dictionary and substitute in the parameter's value:

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    var data = MyIDParam;
    foreach(var kvp in _parameters)
    {
        data = data.Replace("{" + kvp.Key + "}", 
           kvp.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```